# How can I make my website responsive for mobile devices in landscape orientation?

Tags: css

My first personal Website is almost ready! The page is already online!
I have some issues with the responsive design especially in landscape orientation! The landing page is higher than the viewport in landscape orientation, despite I wrote height: 100vh in the css!

Any ideas? Or tipps for make the page responsive also in landscape orientation?

here is my page: www.florian-drums.com

```
     <div id="pic_1">
        <h1 id="title_1"><span>Florian Stöger</span></h1>
        <h2 id="title_2"><span>Musician | Drummer | Teacher</span></h2>    
     </div>


           #pic_1 {
                   background-image: url(Images/Header1.jpeg);
                   background-repeat: no-repeat;
                   background-size: cover;
                   background-attachment: fixed;
                   background-position: center;
                   height: 100vh;
                   width: 100vw;
                  }
```

Comment: Are you talking about `#pic_1`?

Comment: please add your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

In `#pic_1`, the height `height: 100vh` is being overwritten by `height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100)`.

Plus, to deal with unwanted window width increasing beyond 100%, you need to change the margin you are supplying to `#burger div`:

```
#burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-right: 2rem; // <-- reducing margin
    transition: transform, opacity 400ms, 400ms;
}
```

This should make it responsive.

Comment: no it doesn´t! height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100) is the same as 100vh...there is also a little javascript envolved with this line of code... its because the adress field of mobile browsers is included in the viewport height...so without this line of code #pic_1 overlaps the viewport...

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet that I can work with? This will help debug the issue faster.

Comment: Does the answer address your question? Or it's still not fixed?

Comment: The unwanted window width does not come from the burger menu... its from the animiations on #title_1 and #title_2.  Its because overflow hidden doesnt work in mobile browsers, so i had to fix this with a little trick... but its still not perfect like on a desktop...but its fine

Comment: no its still not fixed... on www.responsinator.com it looks fine, except the font-size... but on a real device (i am watching the page on an iphone SE) #pic_1 is higher than the viewport...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196290/discussion-between-mohammed-furqan-rahamath-m-and-florian-stoger).